# component templateUrl not working with spec

Tags: angularjs, testing, mocking, specifications

I'm running tests for an AngularJS component. I think by using templateUrl in my component, my spec/test file fails.

In my spec I have in the beforeAll function

```
element = angular.element('<horizontal-list></horizontal-list>');
element = $compile(element)(scope);
```

I get this error in Jest

> [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: app/global/components/horizontal-list/horizontal-list.tpl.html

How do I get the test to allow $sce to use the resource `templateUrl` in my component?

I know in the module app config I can change the config but I am using `angular-mocks`

**Update for clarification**
How do I make it so that when I run the test, it doesn't error with `blocked loading` for the resource on the templateUrl. This error doesn't occur in the app when run in development or production but it does show in the test.

also:

```
templateUrl: function($sce) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('app/global/components/horizontal-list/horizontal-list.tpl.html')
        }
```

fixes the problem until I run `scope.$apply()` in the test where then I get compile errors where the resource can't be found

Comment: maybe this can help? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#can-i-disable-sce-completely-

Comment: Read [AngularJS Error Reference - $sce:insecurl](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl).

Comment: from what I understand templateUrl calls $sce and trusts the url so why am I having to whitelist the resource url when running a test?